# How to correct this code to load an ImageIcon properly

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the image is not returning anything. I run the location in Windows Run, and it opens it just fine.

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(900,900);
        f.setVisible(true);

        ImageIcon dudey = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\madsa\\Desktop\\JavaStuff\\TestTiles\\Enemy.png");
        JButton one = new JButton("Click the PP", dudey);
        one.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        one.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING); 
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL= painting.class.getResource(path);


        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: You did not add your button to the frame.

Comment: `getResource(path);` expects the `path` to be a path relative to the resources of the class-path. A file system path is very much not that. Try something like `/TestTiles/Enemy.png`.